# Retrieving photos from Google People API results

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

The people.getBatchGet call in the People API returns resources of type Person which have a photos field with a url.

Attempting to retrieve these photos with a GET request to the photo urls authorized with the same credentials used for the people.getBatchGet call results in a 403 error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you give an example of the URL you're using? I haven't been able to get the photos field from my requests.